Inherited @Input() variable initialized in child-constructor is null in ngOnInit only when testing
I am trying to test Angular components with jest. One component initializes an inherited (previously undefined) variable in its constructor. When running the application it works as expected. When I run my test and call MockRender(MyComponent), the variable is initialized in the constructor but when the ngOnInit-Block is reached, it is null (only for testing, not when running the application).
When I completely remove the initialization of the variable from my constructor, it is still changed from undefined to null between constructor-call and ngOnInit.
From my understanding, when a component is set up, the constructor is called and then ngOnInit, so nothing should be able to interfere between those two calls. In addition, I can't find anything in the code that might set the variable to null.
What might be the cause for a variable being reset to null between constructor-call and ngOnInit only when testing, not when running the application?
Edit: I finally managed to get a (not) working minimal example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-oj7kfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest-child%2Ftest-child.component.ts
I missed, that in the parent component, the variable is decorated with @Input(). The reason is: The variable represents a form-group which can be composed of multiple sub-forms from different components OR it represents one of those sub-forms. When it represents multiple sub-forms, it is defined in the corresponding component constructor. When it is a sub-form, it is passed to the parent component via @Input().
When running a test, the parent component sees "there is no value set for the @Input(), so the variable must be null". What I still do not know is, while testing, how I can keep the value assigned in the child component instead of letting the parent component overwrite it with null from @Input().

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens!

The minimal example is basically the one above. It is, however, not reproducible. The question is, if there is anything in the lifecycle of an angular component that might run between constructor and ngOnInit of a component.

ngOnChanges runs the first time BEFORE ngOnInit. Might be the culprit here. I believe it sets null as "missing value" per default if there is no value available.
In Angular, you should treat "ngOnInit" as constructor whenever possible. The constructor is basically out of scope of change detection.

As stated in the question, during tests the @Input() variable is set to null despite being defined in the child class constructor. To avoid this, the code in the parent class was now changed from
@Input()
public input!: string

to
private _input!: string

@Input()
get input(): string {
  return this._input;
}
set input(value: string) {
  if (value) {
    this._input = value;
  }
}

This way, it is possible to set the variable via input or via child class constructor without breaking tests. This workaround is possible because resetting the variable to null/undefined is not desired (at least for our use case).
